# style the focus state of an angular mat-slide-toggle

Tags: angular, sass

What class do I use to style the focus state of a mat-slide-toggle?

From what I can tell via Inspect in the browser it might be something like `::ng-deep .mat-ripple-element .mat-slide-toggle-persistent-ripple` but that's not working. I've tried a couple variations of `ripple` but I can't seem to find the right one, if I'm even looking in the right direction.

What I want is to recolor and shrink the diameter of the pink circle below, I just can't figure out how to select it for the SASS.

[image: mat slide toggle]

HTML:

```
<mat-slide-toggle (change)="onChange($event)">{{ variable-here }}</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am assuming your component is an encapsulated component...

```
$primary-color: #2eb66fl
:host{
/deep/ .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  background-color: rgba($primary-color, 0.54);
}
/deep/ .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
 background: $primary-color;
}
```

> *****below code is to style ripple.*****

```
/deep/ .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: $primary-color;
    }    
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
mat-slide-toggle:focus
```

Comment: just gave it a shot and no dice, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the **::ng-deep pseudo-class to the parent** mat-slide-toggle element.
I have found that targeting shadow DOM elements in Angular Material with ::ng-deep is best done by targeting an element that is declared in your template. (e.g. a wrapper or parent element)

For instance in this case:

```
mat-slide-toggle.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked::ng-deep .mat-ripple-element{
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```